# Oracle Grid 12c [INS-40912] Virtual host name: is assigned to another system on the network

Tags: oracle

When installing Oracle grid 12c the installer shows:

```
[INS-40912] Virtual host name: oel6-12-rac1-vip.localdomain is
assigned to another system on the network.
```

Comment: A common user on this site once said "Oracle is too dumb to lie". It would appear as though you have assigned this hostname to another system on the network.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after testing a few times.

When configuring the Grid I followed this guide:

http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/oracle-db-12cr1-rac-installation-on-oracle-linux-6-using-virtualbox.php#create_db

In the /etc/hosts the virtual host is set:

> ## Virtual

```
192.168.56.103   ol6-121-rac1-vip.localdomain    ol6-121-rac1-vip
192.168.56.104   ol6-121-rac2-vip.localdomain    ol6-121-rac2-vip
```

What I did is - and that was wrong - I plugged the interface for the VIP's but this wrong.
After bringing the IF's down for the VIP's the installer worked.

So the installer just wants to know the hosts/IP of the Vip but does not want the IF's up and running.